# Flutter: How to use InteractiveViewer with a fixed size child?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to have a fixed size artboard, say 1280x1280, and just allow it to be viewable on all devices. With a small amt of padding around it.

No matter what size I give the child content, InteractiveViewer seems to force the contents match my viewport aspect ratio, and then apply padding to those bounds.

Think Sketch or Figma, the size of the artboard doesn't  change, just the viewport does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self answering this, it's `constrained: false`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/constrained.html